# Variable is not assigning to NULL in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm having a procedure which has many BEGIN END; Blocks. In second block variable is not setting to null even if select statement returns null .

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM TEST1; 
 +------+------+
  | ID   | NAME |
  +------+------+
  |    1 | ABCD |
  |    2 | XYZ  |
  +------+------+
  2 rows in set (1.18 sec)

 mysql> SELECT * FROM TEST2;
 +------+------+
 | ID   | NAME |
 +------+------+
 |    1 | BCDF |
 |    2 | FGRT |
 +------+------+
 2 rows in set (0.29 sec)

 mysql> SELECT * FROM TEST3;
 +------+------+
 | ID   | NAME |
 +------+------+
 |   10 | ABCD |
 |   11 | XYZ  |
 +------+------+
 2 rows in set (0.29 sec)

 mysql>
```

PROCEDURE CODE :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTING()
BEGIN
   DECLARE nb INT ;
    BEGIN
        SELECT id INTO nb FROM TEST1 WHERE NAME='ABCD';
        SELECT CONCAT('nb value = ',nb) AS TEST1;
    END;
    BEGIN
        SELECT id INTO nb FROM TEST2 WHERE NAME='ABCD';
        SELECT CONCAT('nb value = ',nb) AS TEST2;
    END;
    BEGIN
        SELECT id INTO nb FROM TEST3 WHERE NAME='ABCD';
        SELECT CONCAT('nb value = ',nb) AS TEST2;
    END;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

RESULT :

```
mysql> CALL TESTING;
+--------------+
| TEST1        |
+--------------+
| nb value = 1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.29 sec)

+--------------+
| TEST2        |
+--------------+
| nb value = 1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)

+---------------+
| TEST3         |
+---------------+
| nb value = 10 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.31 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)
```

In the Above Result for TEST2 select statement  return null But the Variable is holding value 1.I want to know Why and how it can hold null value.

Comment: *In the Above Result for TEST2 select statement return null* That's not right. The query does not return any row. So assigning into variable is not executed at all. So the value is not changed.

Comment: Also concatenation varchar with NULL return NULL `SELECT CONCAT('nb value = ', NULL)` => `NULL`

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=764b6edcee0175b82b298508ee3040a0)

Comment: In PL/SQL block in oracle same kind of  syntax  we have executed and it is taking null value into variable .

Comment: I'm not surprised. This is implementation-dependent because this is not defined in the standard, i.e. may be any.